# Update Database error

Tags: c#, database, winforms, sql-server-ce

I have a form which displays selected datagridviewrow data in textboxes. I would like to edit and update the data from this form and update and save into the datatable when the user clicks update.
When I click update I get an error message:
There was an error parsing the query. [ Token line number = 1,Token line offset = 25,Token in error = ( ]

```
private void editBTN_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    bool notEditable = true;
    if (editBTN.Text == "Update")
    {
        UpdateDataBase();
        editBTN.Text = "Edit";
        deleteBTN.Visible = true;
        notEditable = true;
    }
    else
    {
        deleteBTN.Visible = false;
        editBTN.Text = "Update";
        deleteBTN.Visible = false;
        notEditable = false;
    }
    firstTxt.ReadOnly = notEditable;
    surenameTxt.ReadOnly = notEditable;
    address1Txt.ReadOnly = notEditable;
    address2Txt.ReadOnly = notEditable;
    countyTxt.ReadOnly = notEditable;
    contactTxt.ReadOnly = notEditable;
    emailTxt.ReadOnly = notEditable;
    postTxt.ReadOnly = notEditable;

}

private void UpdateDataBase()
{
    if (MessageBox.Show("Customer information will be updated. This change cannot be undone. Are you sure you want to continue? ", "Confirm Edit", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo) == DialogResult.Yes)
    {
        string constring = @"Data Source=|DataDirectory|\LWADataBase.sdf";
        string Query = "update customersTBL set ([First_Name] = '" + this.firstTxt.Text + "',surename= '" + this.surenameTxt.Text + "',[Address Line 1] = '" + this.address1Txt.Text + "',[Address Line 2] = '" + this.address2Txt.Text + "',County = '" + this.countyTxt.Text + "',[Post Code] = '" + this.postTxt.Text + "' , Email = '" + this.emailTxt.Text + "';,[Contact Number] = '" + this.contactTxt.Text + "');";
        SqlCeConnection conDataBase = new SqlCeConnection(constring);
        SqlCeCommand cmdDataBase = new SqlCeCommand(Query, conDataBase);
        SqlCeDataReader myReader;
        try
        {
            conDataBase.Open();
            myReader = cmdDataBase.ExecuteReader();
            MessageBox.Show("Customer information has been updated", "Update Sucessful");
            while (myReader.Read())
            {

            }
            MessageBox.Show("Please exit the Customers window and re-open to update the table");
            this.Close();
            //displays a system error message if a problem is found
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }

    }
```

Comment: First of all you *really need to use parameters* for this.  But the problem is here `this.emailTxt.Text + "';,[Contact Number] = '"`.  You have a semi-colon there before the end of your update command.  Remove it and it should work.

Comment: You should use parameterized query

Comment: I've removed the semi-colon but still get the same error message

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some problems in your code.
One is trivial and could be easily fixed (remove the semicolon before the `[Contact Number]`, but there are other hidden problems that potentially are more serious.

- First: Remember to always close and dispose the disposable objects
  (connection and command in this case). The using statement ensure
  that the object enclosed by the using block will be correctly closed
  and disposed also in case of exceptions
- Second: Use a parameterized query. This avoids Sql Injections and
  parsing problems. If one or more of your input data contains a single
  quote, the string concatenation used to build the sql command text
  will resul in an invalid command
- Third: An update command acts on all the records present in the table
  if you don't add a WHERE condition. Usually the WHERE condition is
  added to identify the only record that need to be updated and it is
  the value of a field with UNIQUE index or the PRIMARY KEY of your
  table. Of course you could update more than one record with a less
  restrictive WHERE clause but this doesn't seem to be the case
- Fourth: Use the ExecuteNonQuery instead of ExecuteReader for commands
  that update/insert the database (well it works equally but why use a
  method that should be reserved for other uses?)

  ```
  private void UpdateDataBase(int customerID)
  {
       string constring = @"Data Source=|DataDirectory|\LWADataBase.sdf";
       string Query = @"update customersTBL set [First_Name] = @fname,
                    surename = @sur, [Address Line 1] = @addr1,
                    [Address Line 2] = @addr2, County = @county,
                    [Post Code] = @pcode, Email = @mail, [Contact Number] = @ctNo
                    WHERE customerID = @id";
       using(SqlCeConnection conDataBase = new SqlCeConnection(constring))
       using(SqlCeCommand cmdDataBase = new SqlCeCommand(Query, conDataBase))
       {
          try
          {
              conDataBase.Open();
              cndDataBase.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fname", this.firstTxt.Text);
              cndDataBase.Parameters.AddWithValue("@sur", this.surenameTxt.Text );
              cndDataBase.Parameters.AddWithValue("@addr1", this.address1Txt.Text );
              cndDataBase.Parameters.AddWithValue("@addr2", this.address2Txt.Text );
              cndDataBase.Parameters.AddWithValue("@county", this.countyTxt.Text );
              cndDataBase.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pcode", this.postTxt.Text );
              cndDataBase.Parameters.AddWithValue("@mail", this.emailTxt.Text );
              cndDataBase.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ctNo", this.contactTxt.Text );
              cndDataBase.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", customerID );
              int rowsUpdated = cmdDataBase.ExecuteNonQuery();
              if(rowsUpdate == 0)
                  MessageBox.Show("No customer found to update");
          }
          catch (Exception ex)
          {
              MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
          }
      }
  }
  ```

As you can see, with a parameterized query is more difficult to write a bad sql text with hidden problems and the quoting job is passed to the database code that knows better how to format the parameter values.

The only problem that you need to solve is how to retrieve the value for the customerID or some other value that you could use in the WHERE clause to uniquely identify the record of your customer

In this point you call the UpdateDatabase method that now required a UserID variable containing the key to identify your user on the table

```
private void editBTN_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    bool notEditable = true;
    if (editBTN.Text == "Update")
    {
        // Here you need to identify uniquely your modified user
        // Usually when you load the data to edit you have this info extracted from your 
        // database table and you have saved it somewhere 
        // (of course the user should not edit in any way this value
        int UserID = ... ???? (from an hidden textbox? from a global variable, it is up to you
        UpdateDataBase( UserID );
```

Comment: I applaud your typing this all out for the OP.  In a smaller query I might have had the initiative.  Looked at this one and decided, maybe I should just get back to work ;)  Good answer as always Steve!

Comment: Thank you! ill give it a try. as Evan said, thanks for going to a great extent to analyse and repair my code.

Comment: i get this error : No overload for method 'UpdateDataBase' takes 0 arguments

Comment: Of course you need to get the value of the UserID required to execute the update and pass this value when you call the UpdateDatabase method

Comment: When you load the record of your user and put it in the textboxes, you have probably also retrieved the PrimaryKey of your table. This key should be kept for reuse when you call the UpdateDatabase. It is difficult without knowing how you retrieve the record to be edited and what is the table structure of your customersTbl

Comment: if (editBTN.Text == "Update")
                {
                    int UserID = refTxt.Text;
                    UpdateDataBase( UserID );

I get the error code : Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'int'

Comment: int UserID = Convert.ToInt32(refTxt.Text); (Of course the refTxt should contain a string that can be converted to a number, also if it is the primary key of your table you shouldn't allow your user to change it (ReadOnly = True always)

Comment: Thanks Steve, It is the primary key so it will be kept read only.

Answer (score 0):

I think your confusing the Update structure with an Insert.

For your update it looks like this:

update customersTBL set ([First_Name] = 'data', surename= '',[Address Line 1] = '',[Address Line 2] = '',County = '',[Post Code] = '' , Email = '';,[Contact Number] = '');

You need a where clause.

Update/Set does not put the changes in ()

After email you have a ';'

Comment: I've removed the semi colon. Where do I write the "where" clause?

Comment: after the set clause. The way it's currently written, it will update all rows in your database.  Classic blunder.'